# Order meteor find results by index in array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two collections in a Meteor project, loosely created like this:

```
ItemContainer.insert({
  title: title,
  items: [],
});

Items.insert({
  title: title,
});
```

Whenever a new `Item` is created it's id is added to the `items` array in an `ItemContainer`.

I also have a helper like this:

```
Template.body.helpers() {
  items() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    const containerId = instance.state.get("currentContainer");
    const theseItems = ItemContainer.find({ _id: containerId}).items;
    return Items.find({ _id: { $in: items } });
  }
}
```

The issue is that I want to sort the items that I'm returning by their index in the items array. So when I generate a list of items in the browser then the item whose id is at `items[0]` gets displayed first, followed by `items[1]` and so on. Unfortunately I can't find a simple solution in the Mongo docs.

I can think of some ways to do that, like constructing an object by iterating over the items array and returning that, but I have to imagine there's a simpler way. It's also possible for the number of items to grow quite large, in theory thousands or tens of thousands.

Anybody know an easy way to sort by array index?

Comment: hmmm... I may have found a solution:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ .......

But I'm not sure. Won't be able to try it until later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sort items in ascending order when finding through ItemContainer. So that items are returned correct order.

```
const theseItems = ItemContainer.find({ _id: containerId}).sort({"items.0": 1}).items;
```

Comment: Ok, so if the `items` array is sorted before passing into `Items.find()` then the results should appear in order as well? That would be great! I'll try later.